# change element's background by clicking on element

Tags: onclick, getelementbyid

I want to write a very simple script and need some help. Here is what I want the script to do.
There is a div element with no background color by default. When you click on this div it needs to be filled with the red background color. then, when you click on this div again it should have no background again.

CSS code below:

```
 <head>
<style type="text/css">

    #red,#green,#blue,#black{
        width:200px;
        height:100px;
        margin-bottom:25px;
        border:solid red 1px;
    }

</style>
```

HTML and some JS code:

```
 <body>

    <div id='red'></div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--

            var x = document.getElementById('red');

                x.onclick = function(){

                    x.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

        }

        //-->
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the JavaScript, this will work with one click of red and then bring it back to nothing:

```
var clicked = false, 
    x = document.getElementById('red');

x.onclick = function(){
    x.style.backgroundColor = clicked ? 'transparent' : 'red';
    clicked = true;
};
```